# How to use touch screen shield for GLCD?

Tags: lcd, touchscreen, glcd

I know this is a very elementary question. I was wondering if it is possible to use a touch screen shield on a normal GLCD to change it into a touch-GLCD. 
I have seen a product which is a transparent shield with 4 pins (something like the one covering [this module](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/320-240-graphic-lcd-w-touch-screen-and-hw-accel.html)

I searched google for a good tutorial on using this 4-pins device but of no avail. Can anyone give me a manual/tutorial or description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These touches work as resistive touches. the resistance changes as a potentiometer between X1-X2 and Y1-Y2 that can be calculated and translated to the position.
Very good tutorials are  [here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~kjell-e/embedded/doc8091.pdf)   and [here](http://www.pyroelectro.com/tutorials/touchscreen_interface_resistive/theory_touch_screen.html). 
Just search google for "resistive touch screen theory of operation" and tones of answers are there.